# Output a calculation?

Tags: sass

How can I output a calculation in to content?

For example:

```
@for $i from 1 through 8 {
    .list-el {
        $test: calc($i * 10);

        &:before {
            content: '#{$test}';
        }
    }
}
```

The above just outputs the calculation `calc($i * 10)` and not the result. I would expect to see a list of: `10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80`.

Comment: `calc` is not evaluated in Sass, the browser itself receives the formula and evaluates it. You won't be able to output he computed value in Sass.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the 'calc()'.

```
@for $i from 1 through 8 {
    .list-el {
        $test: $i * 10;

        &:before {
            content: '#{$test}';
        }
    }
}
```